# dynamic value in vuetify3 table

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vuetify.js, vuetifyjs3

Opponent1 and Opponent2 are object properties with dynamic values like "horse",  "dog", or what you insert in an input field

```
var a = {
  Rating_Area:1,
  Opponent1: 0,
  Opponent2: 0,
  actions:0,
}
```

The datatable:

```
<v-data-table
    v-model:search="search"
    :items="items">
  <template v-slot:header.stock>
    <div class="text-end">Stock</div>
  </template>
  <template v-slot:item.Opponent1="{ item }">
    <v-rating
      :model-value="item.Opponent1"
      v-model="item.Opponent1"
      color="orange-darken-2"
      density="compact"
      size="small"

    ></v-rating>
  </template>
  <template v-slot:item.Opponent2="{ item }">
    <v-rating
      :model-value="item.Opponent2"
      v-model="item.Opponent2"
      color="orange-darken-2"
      density="compact"
      size="small"

    ></v-rating>
  </template>
  <template v-slot:item.actions="{ item }">
        <div class="text-truncate">
          <v-icon
            small
            @click="deleteItem(item)"
          >
            mdi-delete
          </v-icon>
      </div>
  </template>
</v-data-table>
```

How can I use dynamic values in the template?

The dynamic value is stored in `data` as variable like `this.Opponent2`

```
<template v-slot:item.Opponent2="{ item }">
  <v-rating
    :model-value="item.Opponent2"
    v-model="item.Opponent2"
    color="orange-darken-2"
    density="compact"
    size="small"
  ></v-rating>
</template>
```

Comment: It's not clear what the actual problem is.  If you have a data variable `this.Opponent2` then it is used in the template as `Opponent2`.  What actual error or issue do you run into when trying this?  You should probably include relevant `<script>` code.  HTML template code doesn't reveal that much by itself.